# How can I create a history graph in Wirecloud using history measurements?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am developing a Fiware application and I am using many Fiware GEs (Wirecloud, IoT Agent, Orion, Cygnus, MondoDB, MySQL) that are integrated locally on my linux pc using docker.

I managed to make Orion to receive measurements from a temperature sensor and store them in a MySQL database through Cygnus.

Now, I would like to create a history graph in Wirecloud using those measurements.  I tried to use a History Module to Linear Graph operator that intermediates between an NGSI source operator and a Linear graph widget but I don't know what URL should I use for the HistoryMod Server URL.

I've tried to open the user manual for the History Module operator but the link is broken so I can not read it.

I am posting some images with the [wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxBpY.png), [HistoryModule settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCjk9.png), [NGSI source settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y1LM.png) and the [Linear Graph error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpzZn.png) that I am receiving, for better understanding.

My questions are the following:

1. What URL should I use for the HistoryMod Server URL?
2. Am I wiring the components correctly or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the History Module operator, but I think that your wiring is correct: data resource, operator that request it and a widget to show the results.

In your HistoryModule settings try to change your URL for: http://130.206.82.141:8666/STH/v1/contextEntities/

Did you try to change your Linear Graph widget for a table? (for test that the problem is in the operator and isn't in your widget).

Answer (score 0):

How do you please managed to connect to the database (mysql). I have almost same configuration using `postgres` instead, on a remote server and managed via `docker-compose.`

I can configure everything from the `docker-compose` file, but I don't know how to start `postgres` running, so as to create the database to use.